# ASP.NET boilerplate module's dbcontext recreate abp main tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, boilerplate

I created an ASP.NET boilerplate multi-tenancy startup template from [download page in aspboilerplate website](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates), then created new module in src folder with Application, Core, Entity Framework Core, and Web projects that Main project depends on.

The new module has its own `dbcontext`. I put new entities in the new module that have navigation properties to User table in the main module. Problem is every time I add new migration to the new module , all the tables of abp are recreated, I want just the new tables to be added with the right foreign keys to the main tables.

`ChatUser` in the new module:

```
public class ChatUser : AbpUser<ChatUser>
{}
```

The new entity in the new module :

```
public class Message : CreationAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public long SenderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SenderId))]
    public virtual ChatUser User { get; set; }
}
```

And the new module's `dbContext` is:

```
public class ChatDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<ChatTenant, ChatRole, ChatUser, ChatDbContext>
{
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    public ChatDbContext(DbContextOptions<ChatDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        RegisterConfigurations(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I don't know where the problem is. I tried to put the `dbContext` in new module as:

```
public class ChatDbContext : AbpDbContext
```

but then an exception happens when adding migration:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'ChatUser.CreatorUser' of type 'ChatUser'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'